# Eliminate NA's and bind the two column values and plot the result in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the data with this code

```
dd <- melt(b,id.vars=c("Mesocosm","Exp.day"), measure.vars=myvars)
dd$Exp.day = factor(dd$Exp.day,levels = order(levels(dd$Exp.day)))
ggplot(dd,na.rm=TRUE,aes(x=Exp.day,y=value)) + geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mesocosm)), size = 3,position = position_jitter(width = 0.1)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y")
```

and the data is distorted for the many facets. the dataframe after importing into R doesnt place any NA for most of the blank spaces and after melt there is NA in the Exp.day axis.

I dont have any idea of how to handle the NA's inside the ggplot and also why that Y axis is distorted. Please let me know how to solve these problems.

Here you can see the NA values are not there, I mean you can see at 0 there are no continuous values. (Color is not an issue, but the plotted data is not matching to the dataframe values.) and looks like Y axis has multiple values one over the other. How to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you think the problem I and when i make the plots the y-axis does not look like yours. Be sure you've read the data in correctly and that each column is the class you expect. Be more specific about what "distorted" means to you. And what exactly do you expect to happen to the NA values that is not currently happening? We have no idea what the plots are "supposed" to look like.

Comment: I have added the expected result. and I am using this command to import the dataframe into R.. "b <- read.xls("file_name.xls" , perl = "C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe")"

Comment: You don't need to attempt an edit to the answer to provide feedback, you can put a comment below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ggplot doesn't seem to have an `na.rm` parameter. The best way to remove missing values from your data is to subset them out. Try

```
ggplot(subset(dd, !is.na(Exp.day)),aes(x=Exp.day,y=value), as.table=T) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mesocosm)), size = 3,
        position = position_jitter(width = 0.1)) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y")
```

This gave me

[image]

So it seems when you read your table in, your columns are not being correctly set up as numeric values. They are likely factors in your data.frame but you haven't provided your exact data.frame structure to verify. Just make sure all your numeric columns in your data set are numeric in R and do the necessary conversion if not.

Comment: How did you manage to convert all the columns to Numeric ? I am trying hard but NA's are making my task hard. Please share your method if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: Well, had to download it as an excel file. I removed the second row with the units. I saved as a tab separated text file, and read it in with `read.table()`.